# How to make consistent queries to SQL Server metadata

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

My application needs to cache SQL Server metadata (tables, columns, indexes, etc).

It makes several subsequent queries to system tables and views like `sysobjects`.

Sometimes data synchronization procedure runs simultaneously that creates tables and indexes.

In this case queried metadata becomes inconsistent:

1. Application reads tables and columns lists.
2. Data synchronization procedure creates new table and index.
3. Application reads indexes list, and the new index is for "non-existing" table.

A simple example to reproduce this.

In session 1:

```
-- 0. Drop example table if exists
if object_id('test') is not null drop table test

-- 1. Query tables (nothing returned)
select * from sysobjects where name = 'test'

-- 3. Query indexes (index returned for the new table)
select IndexName = x.name, TableName = o.name
from sysobjects o join sysindexes x on x.id = o.id
where o.name = 'test'
```

In session 2:

```
-- 2. Create table with index
create table test (id int primary key)
```

Is there a way to make metadata queries consistent, something like Schema Modification lock on the entire database or database schema?

Running metadata queries in transaction with serializable isolation level does not help.

Answer (score 0):

You can "simulate" consistency with temp table for sysobjects (tables) and then using this temp table to query for indexes that belong to that tables.
Like this:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#tempTables') is not null
    drop table #tempTables;

select
*
into #tempTables
from sys.objects as o
where o.type = 'U'

select
*
from #tempTables t

select
i.*
from #tempTables t
    inner join sys.indexes as i on t.object_id = i.object_id
```

Comment: That helps for the simplified example from the post. But is much more complicated for the real application code that reads much more metadata.

Comment: I shall "simulate", by the way, if I do not find any other way.